# My computer is unable to connect to Internet

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-connection

I am using Windows 10, and I can't connect to the Internet with Internet Explorer or Google Chrome. I have also Tor Browser, and it is apparently unaffected, because it connects just fine. But can't use it for ordinary browsing.

What's interesting is that Google Chrome and Internet Explorer work just fine on my desktop machine with Windows 7. Even Edge is unable to connect. Why is it that browsers except for Tor are unable to connect on Windows 10, but on Windows 7 they can? Please, help :(

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you tried? Have you ran the Windows network troubleshooter?

Comment: Ran it now, didn't find anything. Pinging favourite sites is fine. What can be problem?

Comment: Curious, what is the output of running `tracert 8.8.8.8` in a Command Prompt window? That command traces a route to Google's DNS server

Comment: Running just now, it will take a time...

Comment: Okay, tracert connected successfully. Two refused to give any informations, but it doesn't matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My computer is unable to connect to Internet

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot :) Reset brings up firewall window. Added exception, and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Returned back to inform you that I made this to command line script. When an issue with connection appears, I just double click the script, allow admin access and good to go. Again thank you, never heard about these commands before :)