# Wi-Fi won't connect to a specific network under Windows

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

## The Problem

I'm running a desktop Windows 11 system with a PCIe add-in card (Intel AX200) for Wi-Fi access.  The system will "connect" to my home network when the password is entered, but there's no internet access, I don't get an IP, and even if I assign a static one, I can't ping the router.

### Troubleshooting Steps

I've tried the following things to help narrow down the source of the problem:

- Booting from a Linux live USB, the computer connects to home network just fine.  This suggests it's a Windows problem, not a hardware problem.
- Connecting to a hotspot network broadcast from my phone also works just fine from inside of Windows.
- I also have an old USB N wifi adapter lying around.  Windows is perfectly happy to connect to the network using that adapter.
- It just so happens that my laptop has the same wifi chipset model; it's able to connect to the home network just fine under Windows.
- Disabling the firewall and antivirus did not help.
- I [reset the TCP/IP stack](https://superuser.com/a/1235746/775092) ([with registry workaround](https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/netsh-int-ip-reset-says-access-denied/))
- I've tried uninstalling the wi-fi adapter from Device Manager and letting Windows Update find a new one; I've also tried downloading the installer myself from Intel's website and running it.  Neither way fixed the problem.
- I also tried sniffing the network traffic with Wireshark for a deeper look.

  - I set my laptop's interface to monitor mode, entered the network's PSK into Wireshark for automatic decryption, then started capturing packets.  On the Windows system, I also installed Wireshark and had it look at the packets on the interface as I pressed the connect button.

[image: Packet capture of DHCP discover being sent]
The DHCPDISCOVER packets are showing up here on the Windows machine, implying that Windows is *trying* to send a DHCPDISCOVER.
[image: Packet capture of DHCP discover... not actually being sent]
This is a screenshot from the Linux laptop in monitor mode; you can see the same string of ARP requests as above (duplicated 3x because of the mesh network), but the DHCPDISCOVER request is missing.  I had the laptop within 3 feet of the desktop, so I don't think it's a signal strength issue.

(My home network is composed of three TP-Link Deco M9 Plus routers in some kind of obtuse mesh configuration; presumably, that's why packets are being duplicated three times on the monitor laptop.)
[image: Packet capture of EAPOL handshake]
I know that Windows is able to send *some* packets using the interface, though, since it associates with the network just fine (EAPOL handshake)

## Summary

My Windows machine won't connect to Wi-Fi.  I *know* it's a software issue, not a hardware one, but reinstalling the Wi-Fi driver, running `netsh int ip reset`, and disabling the firewall didn't fix it.  Short of reinstalling, what else can I try?

Comment: Using an Admin Command, try running NETSH WLAN CONNECT  (use netsh wlan connect /? to get the full syntax).  See if that gives an error message that helps.

Comment: After resetting networking, uninstalling and reinstalling drivers, and re-entering the network password countless times, it turns out that the problem was... Windows' Wi-Fi hotspot feature.  I'd made a startup task to turn on the hotspot a few months ago and forgotten all about it; apparently, just clicking the "off" switch in Settings isn't enough to undo whatever networking changes it makes.  After deleting the startup task and rebooting, the adapter is working as expected again.