# Unable to connect to the Internet on Windows from Windows applications

Tags: windows, networking

I am unable to connect to the internet from Windows, from Windows applications.

Firefox, Edge and Steam are unable to connect.

- Ping works fine (I can ping google.com, no problem)
- Curl works inside a container, can fetch Google.

Things I have done to try to fix it:

- I have tried windows network connection repair.
- I have tried to reset the network configuration.
- I have tried the steps [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/1235743/my-computer-is-unable-to-connect-to-internet) and it didn’t help.
- I have tried my phone as AP, also didn’t work.

Any idea what to try next?

---

**Update**: It partially worked via my phone as AP when my phone is not also using the normal wireless router, when connecting just from mobile network, it worked for some sites Google, yes, YouTube, unable to load complete.

Switching back to the normal WiFi, nothing completes loading... (Except from a container)

I have tried to turn on and off the router, but it didn´t help.

Network works from my other computer and phone via the normal wifi, and yes, it used to work, it basically just stopped, I did not install anything, I was working in GNU Octave (Matlab clone) for the last couple of days before the issue started.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an (incorrect) proxy set?

Comment: Good question, I tried to change the adapter, and now it works, so seems like the adaptor went bad. or is proxy per device, then I will re-enable and check.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, proxy settings are "global" only, so if a different network adapter fixed it, a proxy is probably not to blame. // But device instances on Windows can go bad. Try deleting the network adapter from device manager and then reboot.

Comment: I tried to switch back and delete the adapter in device manager, the problem remains, so it might really be the device that just defunked. (Checked proxy also, all settings are empty). It kinda explains since the problem came out of nowhere, not SW installed. The problem did start after a restart, where I had one additional USB-WIFI adapter plugged in. (Linux compatible).